# Ubuntu can't detect all windows drives as well as external drives

Tags: mount

Ubuntu has been running well on my dual boot system until today. Now I can't detect either external drive or my internal WinXP drives when before all I have to do is mount. Are there any commands or procedures to restore access?

I'm new to Linux. I love how quick and easy it is to navigate with. I'm using Ocelot on my i7 and Lubuntu on my older Centrino Duo laptop. Until today I never had a problem with Ubuntu 11.10.

Intel i7-870 2.93GHz
4GB RAM
1TB / 1.5TB HDDs
GeForce 430
ASUS P7H55M mobo

Answer (score 1):

Caine, as far as folder sharing is concerned with Ubuntu and Windows, what I usually do to make the drive accessible in Linux is install ntfs-3g or ntfs-config.

More information on this wiki page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountingWindowsPartitions%C2%A0